# Tkinter traffic-jamming

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, tkinter

I have an expensive function that is called via a Tkinter callback:

```
def func:  # called whenever there is a mouse press in the screen.
   print("Busy? " + str(X.busy))  # X.busy is my own varaible and is initialized False.
   X.busy = True
   do_calculations()  # do_calculations contains several tk.Canvas().update() calls
   X.busy = False
```

When I click too quickly, the func()'s appear to pile up because the print gives "Busy? True", indicating that the function hasen't finished yet and we are starting it on another thread.

However, print(threading.current_thread()) always gives <_MainThread(MainThread, started 123...)>, the 123... is always the same each print for a given program run. How can the same thread be multiple threads?

Comment: I don't think X.busy will start up a new thread.  Not really a tkinter expert, but I can't find a reference that says that it does spin a thread.

Comment: X is just a (static) class that holds one of my variables. func is called from tkinter.

Comment: OK - why do you believe that your code would start a new thread?  Also, which platform are you running on?  On Windows, at least, Tkinter callbacks are driven from the message loop, and therefore all run on the same thread.

Comment: Because there when I ran it the print statement returned True. How could that happen without there being multiple threads or a thread that is aborted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you're running into recursive message processing.   In particular, `tk.Canvas().update()` will process any pending messages, *including extra button clicks*.  Further, it will do this on the same thread (at least on Windows).

So your thread ID is constant, but your stack trace will have multiple nested calls to `func`.

Comment: ... which is why you should never call `update` until you've learned precisely why you should never call `update`.